# Issue with Sonar installation : Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to install Sonar to get some statistics for my project, But I'm getting this error :

```
 --> Wrapper Started as Console
    Launching a JVM...
    Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
    Could not create the Java virtual machine.
    JVM exited while loading the application.
    Launching a JVM...
    Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
    Could not create the Java virtual machine.
    JVM exited while loading the application.
    Launching a JVM...
    Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
    Could not create the Java virtual machine.
    JVM exited while loading the application.
    Launching a JVM...
    Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
    Could not create the Java virtual machine.
    JVM exited while loading the application.
    Launching a JVM...
    Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
    Could not create the Java virtual machine.
    JVM exited while loading the application.
    There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
      There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
    <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

The script that I'm using to start Sonar is StartSonar :

```
 @echo off setlocal

rem Copyright (c) 1999, 2006 Tanuki Software Inc. rem rem Java Service Wrapper general startup script rem

rem rem Resolve the real path of the wrapper.exe rem  For non NT systems, the _REALPATH and _WRAPPER_CONF values rem  can be hard-coded below and the following test removed. rem if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" goto nt echo This script only works with NT-based versions of Windows. goto :eof

:nt rem rem Find the application home. rem rem %~dp0 is location of current script under NT set _REALPATH=%~dp0

rem Decide on the wrapper binary. set _WRAPPER_BASE=wrapper set
_WRAPPER_EXE=%_REALPATH%%_WRAPPER_BASE%-windows-x86-32.exe if exist "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" goto conf set
_WRAPPER_EXE=%_REALPATH%%_WRAPPER_BASE%-windows-x86-64.exe if exist "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" goto conf set
_WRAPPER_EXE=%_REALPATH%%_WRAPPER_BASE%.exe if exist "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" goto conf echo Unable to locate a Wrapper executable using any of the following names: echo %_REALPATH%%_WRAPPER_BASE%-windows-x86-32.exe echo %_REALPATH%%_WRAPPER_BASE%-windows-x86-64.exe echo %_REALPATH%%_WRAPPER_BASE%.exe pause goto :eof

rem rem Find the wrapper.conf rem :conf set _WRAPPER_CONF="%~f1" if not %_WRAPPER_CONF%=="" goto startup set
_WRAPPER_CONF="%_REALPATH%..\..\conf\wrapper.conf"

rem rem Start the Wrapper rem :startup "%_WRAPPER_EXE%" -c %_WRAPPER_CONF% if not errorlevel 1 goto :eof pause
```

Why this is happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you please post the script you are using to start sonar?

Comment: Are you sure about the JVM? This -really- looks like you are using an old version. Can you output a java -version from the same situation/user that Sonar is launched with?

Answer (score 1):

This seems unlikely, but it appears that the `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` parameter to the JVM was introduced in JDK 1.4.2 - update 12

You're not using an older version of Java that that are you?

Comment: Then you will have to make extra sure that your script is loading the proper version. If possible, please remove any reference to an older JDK on your machine (I know that Windows does some nasty tricks with the registry, making you believe you're using a version but loading another instead).

Comment: You're  right I thought I was using jre7 but when I wrote java -version in cmd it turned out that Windows was using an older version of Java :)

Answer (score 1):

Source of your problem is in the ..\conf\wrapper.conf file.

Put in comment the line :

- wrapper.java.additional.3=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

and try to start SonarQube.

Comment: I'm having now this error : WrapperSimpleApp : Unable to locate the class org.sonar.application.StartServer : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError : org/sonar/application/StartServer(Unsupported major.minor version 50.0 )

Comment: Java 6 or greater is required. Java 5 is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sonar log files itself. You can find server start up logs in the sonar.log file under directory "sonarqube-4.5\logs".

You will find server didnt start due to following port binding exception :

```
2015.12.01 02:46:36 ERROR web[o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind /0.0.0.0:9000
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:411) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
```

Chang the port number to "4950" from "9000" in sonar.properties file under directory "sonarqube-4.5\conf".

```
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
sonar.web.port=4950

# TCP port for incoming HTTPS connections. Disabled when value is -1 (default).
#sonar.web.https.port=-1
```